# Capacitor fast charger

Tags: capacitor, converter

I’m trying to make very fast charger for my 1000 uF 450 V capacitor.

I saw this video on youtube

https://youtu.be/ug82NsxXL94

He managed to charge 1500 uF 450 V capacitor in just 2 seconds.

Fortunately he shared the schematic, but it is little bit confused.

[image]

Can someone explain the concept of this?

Answer (score 1):

The "boost stage" is a fairly typical boost converter based on the 555 timer.  It increases voltage from its input by turning on and off a coil.  This provides current into the capacitor.

[EXAMPLE](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/a-simple-boost-converter-circuit-using-555-timer-ic)

The "cut off" part is a simple comparator circuit that monitors the output of the boost converter and shuts it off when it gets to its voltage set-point.

[EXAMPLE](https://www.circuitstoday.com/voltage-comparator)

Comment: But can you explain more about the factor effecting the output voltage and current? Meaning there are boost converter step the voltage from 12v to 48v while this can step up from 12v to 450v, and since he can fill up a capacitor with this speed so the current also great while it is not in other boost converter

Answer (score 1):

You need to think in terms of energy. When the MOSFET is ON, energy is stored in the inductor. When the MOSFET is OFF, the energy is transfered to the output stage. For an open-loop circuit, the voltage will rise until equilibrium is reached. This occurs when the power (energy per second) in the load equals the energy stored in the inductor per second (minus losses).

For an open-loop system, you need to be careful that the load is sufficient to prevent the voltage from rising too high and causing parts to fail. This is why most boost converters are closed loop.

If you want a faster charge time, you want to: store more energy in the inductor per cycle and/or have more cycles per second, and minimize the losses.

Wikipedia has equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter